# Save id from <select> into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of code in which I can select a user from the database.

```
<html>
<form method="post">
Vak:<select name="gebruiker">
<?php
$resultaat = mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM gebruikers ORDER BY gebruikersnaam") or die("De query op de database is mislukt!");
while ($rij = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultaat)){
    echo "<option value=\"{$rij['id']}\">{$rij['gebruikersnaam']} {$rij['voorletters']} {$rij['achternaam']} {$rij['rol']} {$rij['actief']} {$rij['vak']}</option>";
}
?>
</select><br>
</form>
</html>
```

Now I want to save the ID of the selected user into the variable '$id', but only the ID. I want to use this variable in the following query (at WHERE).

```
<?php
 mysqli_query($mysql,"UPDATE gebruikers SET gebruikersnaam = 
'$gebruikersnaam', wachtwoord ='$wachtwoord',voorletters ='$voorletters', 
achternaam ='$achternaam', rol='$rol',actief='$actief',vak='$vak' WHERE 
id = '$id'") 
or die("De updatequery op de database is mislukt!");
?>
```

I know I can save all the data from the selected user with

```
<?php
$gebruiker = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['gebruiker']);
?>
```

but I only need the ID from the user.
Does someone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In English please.

Comment: ... *in het Engels alstublieft*. (Google translation of "in English please", in Dutch).

Comment: Sorry, It's English now

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your problem, but `$_POST['gebruiker'];` should contain only the id, so `$id = $_POST['gebruiker'];` should work?

Comment: Don't you get 'gebruikersnaam', 'wachtwoord' and all the other columns too?

Comment: You get the value that's behind `option value=` in the `select`, which is `$rij['id']` when you create it, so its just the id. :)

Comment: @Max no, what's inside an `<option>bar, foo</options>` doesn't get sent. Only the value of the selcted option.

Comment: What error are you getting, and if you do a `var_dump($_POST['gebruiker']);` do you get an id of an existing database entry?

Comment: There is no error, but it doesn't adapt the user in the database. In the update query I have "WHERE id='$id' ". But it doesn't find a match, so it wónt adapt a user.

Comment: I want to know how can I store the selected ID into a variable, so I can use this variable at the update query. But I don't want to store the 'gebruikersnaam' and 'wachtwoord' in this variable.